# A family has two children. One child is a girl. What is the probability that the other child is a boy?

Tags: probability

My initial thought process:
Sample space: GG, GB, BG, BB. I then crossed out BG because it's the same as GB because order doesn't matter here. And because we know one is a girl, there leaves two possibilities left. If the other is a boy, the probability should be 1/2, much like how they deduced it [Finding probability of other child also being a boy](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/195151/finding-probability-of-other-child-also-being-a-boy).

However, I was told by my teacher that *the answer is not 1/2*. I'm wondering if any of you guys can see a way in how the question is worded so that it's not 1/2... I don't think there's any other factors?

Comment: This has been asked on this site many times before.  See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/200807/boy-and-girl-paradox), [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/15055/in-a-family-with-two-children-what-are-the-chances-if-one-of-the-children-is-a), [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/195151/finding-probability-of-other-child-also-being-a-boy?),  [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2731/very-simple-conditional-probability-question), [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/26812/the-two-child-problem), ...

Comment: and [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/538471/family-with-two-boys).  Related: [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/198713/why-is-the-probability-of-having-2-boys-7-15) and [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/520844/the-king-comes-from-a-family-of-2-children-what-is-the-probability-that-the-oth).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should not have omitted the BG!

The sample space is (and needs to be) $\{BB, BG, GB, GG\}.$

We know one child is a girl, so that rules out BB. That leaves us with a sample space of BG, GB, GG

In which case the probability that the second child is a boy is $\dfrac 23$.

---

Each of the four outcomes has a probability of $\frac 14$. BG: "Having a boy, and then a girl" is a *different* outcome than $GB:$ having a girl, and then a boy.

To omit one of the boy-girl/girl-boy pairs leaves a sample space of three, with each outcome having probability of 13, which is not correct. Having a boy-girl pair is twice as likely as having two boys, and twice as likely as having 2 girls, and we can only obtain this by counting all four outcomes as distinct, indeed, distinguishable.

Comment: I was thinking about that, but why? You're just taking a pair of children, so whether it's BG or GB shouldn't matter because either way you're getting a girl and boy?

Comment: Because each of the four outcomes has a probability of $\dfrac 14$. Having a boy, and then a girl is a different outcome than having had a girl and then a boy. To omit one of the boy-girl pairs  leaves a sample space of three, with each outcome having probability of $\dfrac 13$, which is not correct. Having a boy-girl pair is twice as likely as having two boys, and twice as likely as having 2 girls, and we can only obtain this by counting all four outcomes as distinct.

Comment: @Adee: It matters because the two possibilities are distinguishable. If you knew that the older child was a girl, then the sample space would be simply $\{GG,GB\}$, where the older child is listed first, and the probability would indeed be $\frac12$. Similarly, if you knew that the younger child was a girl, the probability would be $\frac12$. If you knew that the taller child was a girl, it would be $\frac12$. But all you know here is that one of the children is a girl; if you list the possibilities in the order older-younger, you can rule out only $BB$.

Comment: Thanks for chiming in, @Brian. The word "distinguishable" was on the tip of my tongue, but I couldn't "find" it when I was trying to explain in the comments. I was toying with the older-younger frame, as well, or the analogy between tossing two coins in a row: first coin, second coin...

Comment: @amWhy: Needs another TU +1